# Excel Form Control automatically appearing on new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, form-control

I'm trying to amend an inherited Excel report template that has a checkbox form control on it that I no longer need.  I can manually delete the control box from the active sheet but when I move/copy a new version of that sheet into the workbook it adds a new checkbox onto the original sheet and the new one.  Every time I move/copy that sheet it adds another one.  Trying to find where this is being stored so I can get rid of it.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Is there any code in the `ThisWorkbook` module?

Comment: In ThisWorkbook there's nothing in the (General)/(Declarations) drop downs.  When I switch it to (Workbook) there's a number of subs in the dropdown on the right but they're all pretty well empty, I assumed they're standard.

Comment: What modules are included in this workbook?

Comment: Just one module that I added that houses a macro I wrote.

Comment: Sorry, I think I found it.  The line below shows in my macro, no earthly idea how it got in there.  Commented out and it's solved the problem.  Thanks to anyone who looked at this anyway.ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(667.5, 4.5, 113.25, 10.5).Select